# How to reduce the number “0” size to fit fraction "1/2"?

Tags: matrices, fractions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcommand{\minus}{\scalebox{0.4}[1.0]{$-$}}
\[
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  0&  \minus\frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2} \\
  \minus\frac{1}{2}&  0&\minus\frac{1}{2}\\
  \frac{1}{2}&  \minus\frac{1}{2}&0
\end{bmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to reduce the number “0” size to fit fraction "1/2"? (reduce height of "0" ?)

---

update sample

As below photo shows the proportion close to 1/3

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please add a full MWE, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that.

Comment: As far as I know, it is uncommon to reduce the height of numbers. The package https://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac might be interesting, though.

Comment: How much are you wanting to reduce the 0?  It's already smaller than the fraction 1/2.  Or are you wanting it to be the same size as the 1 or 2?  Have you tried `\dfrac` to increase the size of the fractions?

Comment: @Teepeemm about 1/3 of "1/2"

Comment: @CampanIgnis Thx, I try fit it to the new upload photo(the rendering engine not LaTeX)

Comment: Now I really don't understand.  You seem to be looking at the size of the fractions, but talking about the size of the 0.  And it's not clear if you want something bigger or smaller.  You drew some red lines, and said something was close to 1/3.  What do you mean by that?  What output do you want?  What do you want bigger?  What do you want smaller?

Comment: @Teepeemm I want number "0" smaller and equal to the height between the red horizontal lines

Comment: But the "0" is already the same height as the red horizontal lines.  And how do fractions fit into this?

Answer (score 10):

I would second Mico's recommendation to not do this. But the solution would be to make the fractions display style rather than shrink the zeros (your example was likely set by naïve software which doesn't know how to properly resize fractions. Here's another alternative setting adapted from your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\half}{{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}^1_1}}}
\[
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  0&  -\half &\half \\
  -\half&  0&-\half\\
  \half&  -\half&0
\end{bmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I put the fraction in `\displaystyle` and used a `\vphantom` to add extra spacing—perhaps not enough—above and below the fractions.

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't reduce the size of the `0` numerals. If you believe that they look too big in relation to the text-style `\frac{1}{2}` expressions, maybe what's *really* needed is to replace the `\frac` terms with their decimal representations -- of course while aligning the numbers on their (explicit or implicit decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for 'bmatrix*' env.
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for 'S' column type
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
   0           & -\frac{1}{2} &  \frac{1}{2} \\
  -\frac{1}{2} &  0           & -\frac{1}{2} \\
   \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} &  0
\end{bmatrix*}
\]

\[
\left[ % note: no need to increase the value of '\arraystretch'
\begin{array}{@{} *{3}{S[table-format=-1.1]} @{}}
   0   & -0.5 &  0.5 \\
  -0.5 &  0   & -0.5\\
   0.5 & -0.5 &  0
\end{array} 
\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Compare to decimal shows i prefer to put the matrix element have same layout as new upload photo.

Comment: @user67646 - The second screenshot you posted strongly suggests using a third option: Keep the `bmatrix*` environment, but (a) replace all instances of `\frac` with `\dfrac` and (b) change `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}` to `\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}`.

Answer (score 5):

The image which the OP posted looks like display style fractions `\dfrac` were used. As stated in my comment, shrinking the `0` in these situations is uncommon. Generally speaking, the various `Tex` engines and most trusted and well used packages have good typographic features by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools,xfrac}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcommand{\minus}{\scalebox{0.4}[1.0]{$-$}}
\[
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  0&  \minus\frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2} \\
  \minus\frac{1}{2}&  0&\minus\frac{1}{2}\\
  \frac{1}{2}&  \minus\frac{1}{2}&0
\end{bmatrix*}
\]



\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}%You will see what happens if you do not use it. It is a local definition which does not affect the third matrix
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  0&  -\dfrac{1}{2} &\dfrac{1}{2} \\
  -\dfrac{1}{2}&  0&-\dfrac{1}{2}\\
  \dfrac{1}{2}&  -\dfrac{1}{2}&0
\end{bmatrix*}
\]


\[
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  0&  \sfrac{-1}{2} &\sfrac{1}{2} \\
  \sfrac{-1}{2}&  0&\sfrac{-1}{2}\\
  \sfrac{1}{2}&  \sfrac{-1}{2}&0
\end{bmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Top: original; middle: `\dfrac`; bottom: https://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac.

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `c` for the `sfrac` `bmatrix` whilst for the `others` you use `r`?

Comment: @albert Thank you. I have changed that for consistency.

Answer (score 5):

A good solution, in my opinion, to reduce the size discrepancy between fractions (in text mode by default) and ordinary numbers is to use the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath`, which are ca 80 % of \displaystyle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' env.
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

    \[ \setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    \phantom{-}0 & -\mfrac{1}{2} & \mfrac{1}{2} \\
     -\mfrac{1}{2} & 0 & -\mfrac{1}{2} \\
    \mfrac{1}{2} & -\mfrac{1}{2} & 0
    \end{bmatrix*} 
    \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is something wrong with the alignment of the middle column. The 0 is slightly to the right it seems.

Comment: @Anush: You're right. When I measure it, the difference in position is 0.8pt (~ 0.28mm).I don't where it comes from. Maybe the side bearings of the fraction? You can add `\mkern 1.5mu` after the 0 to compensate.

Comment: @Bernard It's work!

Comment: @Anush Thank u for your notice!

Answer (score 4):

I would say that your sample actually suggests the opposite: "I want to preserve regular size even for numerators and denominators". Use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`.

Also, why do you have special treatment for minus? Why the `-` isn't enough?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\[
  \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
    0             &  -\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{2}  \\
    -\dfrac{1}{2} &  0             & -\dfrac{1}{2} \\
    \dfrac{1}{2}  &  -\dfrac{1}{2} & 0
  \end{bmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think your middle column has something wrong with its alignment. The 0 seems shifted to the right. Is that an illusion?

Comment: I just used the same alignment as the question author had in the question. And every fraction line has something extra on both sides, that's the root cause.